# SVG images formatting issues in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, formatting

I'm trying to achieve a similar effect to Lando Norris' [website](https://landonorris.com/) where his achievements scroll horizontally. I tried recreating that by creating svg images and then formatting them with the help of css. It doesn't seem to work on most web browsers though. Should I change my approach at recreating this horizontal banner or is there a way to make the images display properly?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>PawelosFPV achievements</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo+Tamma|PT+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
  <style>
    *,
    *::before,
    *::after {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    :root {
      font-family: "PT Sans", sans-serif;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    body {
      background-color: #EFF1ED;
      min-height: 100vh;
    }
    
    h1 {
      color: #161032;
      font-family: "Baloo Tamma", sans-serif;
      font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
    
    h1::after {
      background-color: #00A8E8;
      bottom: 0;
      content: "";
      display: block;
      height: 0.25rem;
      position: absolute;
      width: 1rem;
    }
    
    p {
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    }
    
    .container {
      margin: 0 auto 2rem;
      max-width: 900px;
      padding: 0 1.5rem;
    }
    
    .sample-item {
      width: auto;
      height: 125px;
      vertical-align: middle;
      padding-right: 20px;
    }
    
    .horizontal-scrolling-banner {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .horizontal-scrolling-banner__helper-wrapper {
      align-items: center;
      display: flex;
      left: 0;
      transform: translateZ(0);
      transition-property: left;
      transition-timing-function: linear;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
  <div class="container">

  </div>

  <div class="horizontal-scrolling-banner">
    <img src="http://pawelosfpv.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/FAI-World-Drone-Cup-Riga-2018.svg" class="sample-item">
    <img src="http://pawelosfpv.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/FAI-World-Drone-Cup-Modena-2018.svg" class="sample-item">
    <img src="http://pawelosfpv.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/Sumo-Challange-2018.svg" class="sample-item">
    <img src="http://pawelosfpv.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/Polish-Junior-Championship-2019.svg" class="sample-item">
    <img src="http://pawelosfpv.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/Polish-Championship-2019-V2.svg" class="sample-item">
    <img src="http://pawelosfpv.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/Drone-Champions-League-2019.svg" class="sample-item">
    <img src="http://pawelosfpv.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/DCL-Salina-Turda-2019.svg" class="sample-item">
    <img src="http://pawelosfpv.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/DCL-VADUZ-2019.svg" class="sample-item">
    <img src="http://pawelosfpv.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/DCL-TURIN-2019.svg" class="sample-item">
    <img src="http://pawelosfpv.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/VICE-FAI-World-Cup-Ranking-2019.svg" class="sample-item">
    <img src="http://pawelosfpv.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/DRL-Tryouts-2019.svg" class="sample-item">
    <img src="http://pawelosfpv.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/DCL-Laax-2019.svg" class="sample-item">
    <img src="http://pawelosfpv.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/IDSC-Korea-Yeongwol.svg" class="sample-item">
    <img src="http://pawelosfpv.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/EPFL-FAI-2019.svg" class="sample-item">
    <img src="http://pawelosfpv.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/XFLY-Tianjin-2019.svg" class="sample-item">
    <img src="http://pawelosfpv.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/FAI-World-Drone-Cup-Partouche-2019.svg" class="sample-item">
    <img src="http://pawelosfpv.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/DRL-Tryouts-2020.svg" class="sample-item">
    <img src="http://pawelosfpv.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/Drone-Champions-League-2020.svg" class="sample-item">

  </div>
  </div>
  <!-- partial -->
  <script>
    (function horizontalScrollingBanner() {
      var banners = document.getElementsByClassName('horizontal-scrolling-banner');
      if (!banners || banners.length === 0) {
        return;
      }
      var pxPerSecond = 25;
      setUpElements();
      scrollTheBanners();
      window.addEventListener('resize', setUpElements);

      function setUpElements() {
        for (var i = 0; i < banners.length; i++) {
          var currentBanner = banners[i];
          var helperWrapperClass = 'horizontal-scrolling-banner__helper-wrapper';
          var currentHelperWrapper = currentBanner.querySelector('.' + helperWrapperClass);
          if (currentHelperWrapper) {
            var clones = currentHelperWrapper.querySelectorAll('[data-clone]');
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(clones, function(clone) {
              clone.remove();
            });
            var childrenCount = currentHelperWrapper.children.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++) {
              currentBanner.appendChild(currentHelperWrapper.children[0]);
            }
            currentHelperWrapper.remove();
          }

          var children = currentBanner.children;

          var bannerWidth = currentBanner.getBoundingClientRect().width;
          var minWidthToCoverBanner = (bannerWidth * 2) + children[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
          var childrenWidth = Array.prototype.reduce.call(children, function(r, child) {
            return r + child.getBoundingClientRect().width;
          }, 0);
          var currentWidth = childrenWidth;


          do {
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(children, function(child) {
              var clone = child.cloneNode();
              clone.setAttribute('aria-hidden', true);
              clone.dataset.clone = true;
              currentBanner.appendChild(clone);
            });
            currentWidth += childrenWidth;
          } while (currentWidth < minWidthToCoverBanner);

          var transitionHelperWrapper = document.createElement('div');
          transitionHelperWrapper.classList.add('horizontal-scrolling-banner__helper-wrapper');
          var childrenCount = children.length;
          for (var i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++) {
            transitionHelperWrapper.appendChild(children[0]);
          }
          currentBanner.appendChild(transitionHelperWrapper);
          transitionHelperWrapper.dataset.childrenWidth = childrenWidth;
        }
      }

      function scrollTheBanners() {
        for (var i = 0; i < banners.length; i++) {
          var helperWrapper = banners[i].firstElementChild;
          var childrenWidth = helperWrapper.dataset.childrenWidth;
          var offsetLeft = helperWrapper.offsetLeft;

          if (offsetLeft <= (childrenWidth * -1)) {
            helperWrapper.style.transitionDuration = '0s';
            helperWrapper.style.left = '0px';
            helperWrapper.style.removeProperty('transition-duration');
          } else if (helperWrapper.style.left === '' || helperWrapper.style.left === '0px') {
            setTimeout(function() {
              helperWrapper.style.transitionDuration = (childrenWidth / pxPerSecond).toFixed() + 's';
              helperWrapper.style.left = (childrenWidth * -1) + 'px';
            }, 0);
          }
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(scrollTheBanners);
      }
    })();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: *"It doesn't seem to work on most web browsers"* What doesn't work exactly?

Comment: Maybe a simpler solution? https://jsfiddle.net/kpcf8jug/

Comment: The achievements is a simple `carousel` to which you find many tutorials, guides or libraries.

Answer (score 1):

### Fonts are are not automatically embedded

Locally installed fonts used in svg are not available for users of your website/app unless they happen to have this particular font installed.

Besides **firefox usually rejects local font file usage** due to security policies (could be changed in [settings as described here: "Custom (System installed) fonts in Firefox?"](https://support.mozilla.org/no/questions/1355994#answer-1455437))

**Some options:**

- Open your svg in Illustrator and convert text to (path) outlines before saving as svg via convert text to outlines selcting all elements by <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> should do the trick
- embed the font via `@font-face` using a data URL. A tool like [transfonter](https://transfonter.org) can help

You should also concider using an open source alternative to your font like the SIL OFL v1.1 licensed "D-Din" available on [font squirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/d-din)

#### Still weird letter spacing?

Illustrator often splits text elements into seperate `<text>`or `<tspan>` elements. This is usually caused by customized spacing/kerning values.

```
<text class="cls-1" transform="translate(133.05 117.67)">2018</text>
<text class="cls-2" transform="translate(143.07 61.95)">1<tspan class="cls-3" x="19.99" y="0">S</tspan>
<tspan x="39.83" y="0">T</tspan>
</text><text class="cls-4" transform="translate(57.23 179.3)">SUMO CHAL<tspan class="cls-5" x="147.92" y="0">L</tspan>
<tspan x="162.25" y="0">ANGE</tspan>
</text>
```

Unfortunately markup will only work for this particular font. So you might need to simplify your structure like so:

```
<text x="50%" y="30%" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central">2022<tspan x="50%" data-dx="50%" dy="15%">1ST</tspan></text>
<text x="50%" y="90%" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central">
AWARD
</text>
```

#### Example: embedded vs not embedded font

```css
img,
svg{
  height:200px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:wght@700" rel="stylesheet">

<p>Font embedded</p>
  <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/iW8.svg" class="sample-item">
<p>Font not embedded (fallback font is used)</p>
  <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/iY4.svg" class="sample-item">
  
<p>Inline SVG - using Webfont (Roboto)</p>
<svg  id="Achievement" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 185">
  <defs>
    <style>
      text {
font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
        font-size: 32px;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <path id="wreath" d="M2.4 88.7c0-0.3 8.9 0.8 20.8 12.8a58.6 58.6 0 0 1-4.3-8.9c-13.4-3.7-15.9-9.4-19-19.5c1.3 2.6 10.3 4.8 12.7 9c1.8 3.3 3.8 6.4 5.5 8a51.4 51.4 0 0 1-1.9-8.3c-0.1-0.5-0.1-0.9-0.2-1.3c-4.4-2.2-14.6-9.4-15.3-23.2c2 2.9 9.3 2.6 14.9 18.5a82.9 82.9 0 0 1 0.2-9.3c-4.3-3.5-12.5-13.9-11-35c1.7 3.3 10.4 14.3 10.8 21.9a60.7 60.7 0 0 0 0.8 7.3c0.1-0.6 0.1-1.1 0.2-1.7a67.3 67.3 0 0 1 1.6-8.2a26.1 26.1 0 0 0-4.7-10.9a9.8 9.8 0 0 1-1.1-11c1.2-2.6 0.6-8.5 0.6-8.5s8.2 8.2 6.1 27.4a61.7 61.7 0 0 1 2.7-6.9a15.3 15.3 0 0 0-1.3-8.7c-2.2-4.7-4.8-12 1.3-22.9c0.1 4.3 3.8 11.4 3.4 16.9a76.8 76.8 0 0 1-1.8 11.5a57.8 57.8 0 0 1 3.7-6c0.3-2.9-1.1-7-0.9-14.2c0.2-8.7 4-10.5 4.9-15.2c3.4 9 1.5 19.4-1.2 25.6l0.8-1c0.9-1.2 1.8-2.3 2.6-3.4a35.1 35.1 0 0 1 3.7-15.4c1.7-3 6.8-5.5 6.9-8c1.3 9.3-3.2 15.6-7.3 20.2l0 0.1a14.6 14.6 0 0 1 16-2.8s-5.3 4.9-9.7 5.3c-4.2 0.3-6.3 0-8.6 1.4c-0.7 1-1.6 2.1-2.5 3.2c5.7-3.1 14.2-0.1 17.5 2c-4.8 3.8-9.6 2.9-12.3 1.1c-2.4-1.6-5.2-0.1-6.9-0.9a70.2 70.2 0 0 0-4.4 6.3a61.2 61.2 0 0 0-3.7 7.8c3.1-4.4 8.5-9.7 15.3-9.9c-0.2 2.8-3.3 8.2-7.7 10.7c-3.6 2-7.3 2.9-9.4 4.7a65.1 65.1 0 0 0-2 10v0.1c4-10.1 15.2-14.7 18.2-14.9c0 0-5 3.6-5.3 8.3s-4.8 7.2-8.8 8.5a8.8 8.8 0 0 0-4.7 4.1a77.5 77.5 0 0 0 0 12.9c1.3-19.3 14.5-19.3 14.5-19.3a7.8 7.8 0 0 0-2.4 5c-0.4 3.4-1.2 6.1-5.3 10.6a21 21 0 0 0-5.5 11.3a54 54 0 0 0 5.8 13.9c-2.4-6-3.9-14.4-0.8-21.7c0.5 4.2 6.8 10.4 6.8 15.6c0 4.5-1.8 10.4-0.3 14.2c0.8 0.9 1.6 1.9 2.5 2.8c-0.4-2.7-0.1-6.7-0.7-9.5c1.5 2.2 2.4 8.2 3.4 12.3a71 71 0 0 0 6 5.1c-5.1-6-7.7-15.7-6.6-24.8c3.7 3.6 8.7 11.1 8.9 16.9a28.1 28.1 0 0 0 3.7 11.9l1.1 0.6c1.1 0.6 2.3 1.2 3.4 1.7c-5.6-5-7-14.1-7-18.1c6.3 4.4 13 14.6 13.8 20.6c1.2 0.3 2.4 0.6 3.6 0.9c4.8 0.9 10.2 1 14.5-1.3l0.3 0.5h0l0.3 0.5l0.5 1c-5.1 2.6-10.9 2.5-16 1.5a47.4 47.4 0 0 1-5.5-1.5c-2.3 3.8-8.5 7.2-12.4 6.8s-8.2-2.4-10.9-1.5c3.6-6 9.8-7.7 13.9-6.3c3.6 1.2 6.1 1.6 8 0.5a56.2 56.2 0 0 1-7.5-3.4l-1-0.5c-4.9 3-11.2 2.5-15.3 1.1c-4.6-1.5-6.3-6.1-10.1-8.1c9.6-2.5 14.8 0.9 17 3a9.8 9.8 0 0 0 6.5 2.9a66.4 66.4 0 0 1-10.3-7.9c-2.7-0.1-8.3 1.7-12.4-1.7c4-1.3 7.1-1.7 9.8-0.9c-0.9-0.9-1.7-1.8-2.5-2.8c-3.1 0.1-8.7 2-13-0.4a70.7 70.7 0 0 1-10.9-8.1s7.3-0.3 11.2 0.7c-3.6-2-14.3-13.4-14.3-13.7z" />
  <use href="#wreath" style="transform: translate(100%,0) scale(-1, 1);" />
  </use>
  <text x="50%" y="30%" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central">2022<tspan x="50%" data-dx="50%" dy="15%">1ST</tspan></text>
  <text x="50%" y="90%" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central">
    AWARD
  </text>
</svg>
```

Inline svg (appended to your html body) could use webfonts loaded via `@font-face`. Unfortunately your carousel script apparenty only support single elements (without nested child nodes).